# How can I separate funnels for the same destination but different paths

Tags: google-analytics

I have two goal funnels setup in Google Analytics. One tracks the progression of the user from a gift registry to a checkout and looks something like this:

1. Step 1:/gift-registry.aspx
2. Step 2: /Checkout/Basket.aspx
3. Step 3: /Checkout/Details.aspx
4. Step 3: /Checkout/Confirm.aspx

The other is a non-gift registry or a regular checkout that goes something like:

1. Step 1: /Checkout/Basket.aspx
2. Step 2: /Checkout/Details.aspx
3. Step  3: /Checkout/Confirm.aspx

Trouble is, I see exactly the same transactions and conversion rate on both of them. I'm guessing this is because the last 3 steps are the same in both. Is there a way to differentiate conversions from the gift registry from regular purchases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set that certain steps in a goal funnel are "Mandatory". You click the little box right next to the step in GA. Does this fix it?

Comment: Required only works on the 1st step.  Ex: `/1`, `/2`, `/goal`.  Someone who goes directly from `/1` to `/goal` will showup as having "fell through" `/2` in the funnel visualization. Vs someone who enters on `/2` and then proceeding to `/goal` will not show up at all.